# Multiple Poisson Plots with Different Lambda using stat_function

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to do multiple PDF bar chart using stat_function (don't want to do tidyverse or anything) . Using ggplot2.

I am sure I am making a simple error but can't figure out what I am doing...

```
 library(ggplot2)


lambda1 <- function(x) dpois(x, lambda = 2)
lambda2 <- function(x) dpois(x, lambda = 5)

#Define the plot ranges and assign a factor to each function
plot.range1 <- data.frame(x=c(0,15), Functions = factor(1))
plot.range2 <- data.frame(x=c(0,15), Functions = factor(2))

ggplot(NULL, aes(x=x, colour=Functions)) +
   stat_function(data = plot.range1, fun = lambda1, size = 1.5) +
   stat_function(data = plot.range2, fun = lambda2, size = 1.5) +

  geom_bar()+

  theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
   scale_colour_manual("Parameters", guide="legend", 
                  labels = c("2", "5"), 
                  values= c("orange", "blue"))
```

Trying to achieve the following...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCTXj.png)

Comment: The issue is that `geom_bar` also expects a dataset if you provide a mapping. But as you have neither provided a local dataset via `data=` nor a global dataset via `ggplot()` you will get an error.

Comment: Okay... not sure how to fix in my code??

Comment: I would help if you could clarify what you are trying to achieve with adding a `geom_bar`?

Comment: added image I am trying to achieve in the problem description

Comment: Thank you both so much for the posted answers.... I knew it would be something simpler that what I was trying as ggplot code is usually short to get something done.  I was making it way too complex.... I voted for the answers ...I think that's what I am supposed to do...

Answer (score 0):

As you want a barchart I would suggest to compute the density values outside of `ggplot()` and put them in a dataframe. Then use a `geom_col` to create your chart:

```r
library(ggplot2)

dat <- expand.grid(
  x = seq(0, 15, 1),
  lambda = c(2, 5)
)
dat$y <- dpois(dat$x, lambda = dat$lambda)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = factor(lambda))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
  scale_fill_manual("Parameters",
    values = c("orange", "blue")
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(x = rep(1:15, 2), lambda = rep(c(2, 5), each = 15))

d |>
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = dpois(x, lambda),
             fill = as.factor(lambda),
             group = lambda)
         ) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')
```

[image: dodged bar plot]

(add scales etc. like in your example)